# Agregar JSON al HTML desde JQuery

Tags: jquery, html5, json

Necesito agregar toda mi informacion que tengo en el JSON al HTML desde JQuery, pero el inconveniente que llego a tener es que me pierdo con los tantos arreglos que tengo (son pocos).

Necesito saber si hay alguna otra forma que sea más fácil de realizar con alguna función, si este no es el caso, estoy atorado en una cierta parte ya que no se acomodan de la forma en la que yo requiero en el codigo (después de  agregar la variable `salto` necesito seguir poniendo otro `input` y se repite el ciclo 5 veces, despues de eso, todo lo que esta encerrado en un "div" va a abarcar mi primera pregunta asi que hasta ahí se cierra mi `div` y abro nuevamente otro `div` para otra pregunta y se vuelve a cerrar, esto es 3 veces para poder cerrar mi `div` con clase `main`), pero no sé qué está mal, por esa parte propuse la primera idea antes explicada.

**JSON**

```
var informacion={
    "titulo":"Pratica 1",
    "cantidad_Preguntas":3,
    "preguntas":[{
        "pregunta_1":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
            "respuestas_pregunta1":[{
                "respuesta1_pregunta1":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta1_A":"Países",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta1_A":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
                }],
                "respuesta2_pregunta1":[{
                    "respuesta2_pregunta1_B":"Municipios",
                    "ayuda2_pregunta1_B":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta3_pregunta1":[{
                    "respuesta3_pregunta1_C":"Estados_/_provincias",
                    "ayuda3_pregunta1_C":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta4_pregunta1":[{
                    "respuesta4_pregunta1_D":"Continentes",
                    "ayuda4_pregunta1_D":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                    "correcta":true
                }],
                "respuesta5_pregunta1":[{
                    "respuesta5_pregunta1_E":"Islas",
                    "ayuda5_pregunta1_E":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
                }]
            }],
        "pregunta_2":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
            "respuestas_pregunta2":[{
                "respuesta1_pregunta2":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta2_A":"Países",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta2_A":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
                }],
                "respuesta2_pregunta2":[{
                    "respuesta2_pregunta2_B":"Municipios",
                    "ayuda2_pregunta2_B":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta3_pregunta2":[{
                    "respuesta3_pregunta2_C":"Estados_/_provincias",
                    "ayuda3_pregunta2_C":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta4_pregunta2":[{
                    "respuesta4_pregunta2_D":"Continentes",
                    "ayuda4_pregunta2_D":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                    "correcta":true
                }],
                "respuesta5_pregunta2":[{
                    "respuesta5_pregunta2_E":"Islas",
                    "ayuda5_pregunta2_E":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
                }],
        "pregunta_3":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
            "respuestas_pregunta3":[{
                "respuesta1_pregunta3":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta3_A":"Países",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta3_A":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
                }],
                "respuesta2_pregunta3":[{
                    "respuesta2_pregunta3_B":"Municipios",
                    "ayuda2_pregunta3_B":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta3_pregunta3":[{
                    "respuesta3_pregunta3_C":"Estados_/_provincias",
                    "ayuda3_pregunta3_C":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta4_pregunta3":[{
                    "respuesta4_pregunta3_D":"Continentes",
                    "ayuda4_pregunta3_D":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                    "correcta":true
                }],
                "respuesta5_pregunta3":[{
                    "respuesta5_pregunta3_E":"Islas",
                    "ayuda5_pregunta3_E":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var div_main=$("<div></div>").addClass("main");
    var body=$("body");
    var div_pregunta=$("<div></div>")
    var pregunta1=$("<p></p>").text(informacion.preguntas[0].pregunta_1);
    var formm=$("<form></form>").attr("action","");
    //
    var input_pregunta1_respuesta1001=$("<input>",{
         type:"radio", 
         name:"pregunta1", 
         value:"1001", 
         id:"respuesta1001"
    });
    var label_input_pregunta1_respuesta1001=$("<label></label>").attr("for","respuesta1001").text(informacion.preguntas[0].respuestas_pregunta1[0].respuesta1_pregunta1[0].respuesta1_pregunta1_A);
    var p_ayuda1_pregunta1_A=$("<p></p>").attr("id","ayuda1001").text(informacion.preguntas[0].respuestas_pregunta1[0].respuesta1_pregunta1[0].ayuda1_pregunta1_A);
    var salto=$("<br>");
    /*
    var input_pregunta1_respuesta1002=$("<input>",{
         type:"radio", 
         name:"pregunta1", 
         value:"1002", 
         id:"respuesta1002"
    });
    var label_input_pregunta1_respuesta1002=$("<label></label>").attr("for","respuesta1002").text(informacion.preguntas[0].respuestas_pregunta1[1].respuesta2_pregunta1[0].respuesta2_pregunta1_B);
    var p_ayuda2_pregunta1_B=$("<p></p>").attr("id","ayuda1002").text(informacion.preguntas[0].respuestas_pregunta1[1].respuesta2_pregunta1[0].ayuda2_pregunta1_B);
*/
    body.append(
        div_main.prepend(
            div_pregunta.prepend(pregunta1).append(
                    formm.append(input_pregunta1_respuesta1001).append(label_input_pregunta1_respuesta1001).append(p_ayuda1_pregunta1_A).append(salto)
            )
        )
    );
```

**HTML**
Este es el resultado que necesito realizar

```html
<body>
 <div class="main">
  <!--PREGUNTA1-->
<div>
    <p>¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?</p>
    <form action="">
        <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" value="1001" id="respuesta1001">
        <label for="respuesta1001">Países</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda1001">Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" value="1002" id="respuesta1002">
        <label for="respuesta1002">Municipios</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda1002">División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" value="1003" id="respuesta1003">
        <label for="respuesta1003">Estados / provincias</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda1003">Pueblo organizado en un territorio sometido a un único poder.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" value="1004" id="respuesta1004">
        <label for="respuesta1004">Continentes</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda1004">Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" value="1005" id="respuesta1005">
        <label for="respuesta1005">Islas</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda1005">Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua.</p><br>
            <input type="button" name="pregunta1" id="boton1" value="Validar">
    </form> 
</div>
<!--PREGUNTA2-->
<div>
    <p>¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?</p>
    <form action="">
        <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" value="2001" id="respuesta2001">
        <label for="respuesta2001">Países</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda2001">Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" value="2002" id="respuesta2002">
        <label for="respuesta2002">Municipios</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda2002">División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" value="2003" id="respuesta2003">
        <label for="respuesta2003">Estados / provincias</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda2003">Pueblo organizado en un territorio sometido a un único poder.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" value="2004" id="respuesta2004">
        <label for="respuesta2004">Continentes</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda2004">Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" value="2005" id="respuesta2005">
        <label for="respuesta2005">Islas</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda2005">Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua.</p><br>
            <input type="button" name="pregunta2" id="boton2" value="Validar">
    </form> 
</div>
<!--PREGUNTA3-->
<div>
    <p>¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?</p>
    <form action="">
        <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" value="3001" id="respuesta3001">
        <label for="respuesta3001">Países</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda3001">Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" value="3002" id="respuesta3002">
        <label for="respuesta3002">Municipios</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda3002">División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" value="3003" id="respuesta3003">
        <label for="respuesta3003">Estados / provincias</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda3003">Pueblo organizado en un territorio sometido a un único poder.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" value="3004" id="respuesta3004">
        <label for="respuesta3004">Continentes</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda3004">Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.</p>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" value="3005" id="respuesta3005">
        <label for="respuesta3005">Islas</label><br>
            <p id="ayuda3005">Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua.</p><br>
            <input type="button" name="pregunta3" id="boton3" value="Validar">
    </form> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Podrías ser un poco mas descriptivo con lo que esperas obtener. Quisiera ayudarte pero es algo confusa tu pregunta. Colocar un resultado de ejemplo sería conveniente.

Comment: ya agrege el como necesito que sea ve cuando se abra el HTML

Comment: Puedes indicarme si te ha funcionado o no la solución propuesta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la estructura del JSON no puede ser modificada, acá está la solución.

```js
var informacion={
    "titulo":"Pratica 1",
    "cantidad_Preguntas":3,
    "preguntas":[{
        "pregunta_1":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
        "respuestas_pregunta1":{
            "respuesta1_pregunta1":{
                "respuesta1_pregunta1_A":"Países",
                "ayuda1_pregunta1_A":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
            },
            "respuesta2_pregunta1":{
                "respuesta2_pregunta1_B":"Municipios",
                "ayuda2_pregunta1_B":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },
            "respuesta3_pregunta1":{
                "respuesta3_pregunta1_C":"Estados_/_provincias",
                "ayuda3_pregunta1_C":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },
            "respuesta4_pregunta1":{
                "respuesta4_pregunta1_D":"Continentes",
                "ayuda4_pregunta1_D":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                "correcta":true
            },
            "respuesta5_pregunta1":{
                "respuesta5_pregunta1_E":"Islas",
                "ayuda5_pregunta1_E":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
            }
        }
    },{
        "pregunta_2":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
        "respuestas_pregunta2":{
            "respuesta1_pregunta2":{
                "respuesta1_pregunta2_A":"Países",
                "ayuda1_pregunta2_A":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
            },
            "respuesta2_pregunta2":{
                "respuesta2_pregunta2_B":"Municipios",
                "ayuda2_pregunta2_B":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },
            "respuesta3_pregunta2":{
                "respuesta3_pregunta2_C":"Estados_/_provincias",
                "ayuda3_pregunta2_C":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },
            "respuesta4_pregunta2":{
                "respuesta4_pregunta2_D":"Continentes",
                "ayuda4_pregunta2_D":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                "correcta":true
            },
            "respuesta5_pregunta2":{
                "respuesta5_pregunta2_E":"Islas",
                "ayuda5_pregunta2_E":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
            }
        }
    },{
        "pregunta_3":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
        "respuestas_pregunta3":{
            "respuesta1_pregunta3":{
                "respuesta1_pregunta3_A":"Países",
                "ayuda1_pregunta3_A":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
            },
            "respuesta2_pregunta3":{
                "respuesta2_pregunta3_B":"Municipios",
                "ayuda2_pregunta3_B":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },
            "respuesta3_pregunta3":{
                "respuesta3_pregunta3_C":"Estados_/_provincias",
                "ayuda3_pregunta3_C":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },
            "respuesta4_pregunta3":{
                "respuesta4_pregunta3_D":"Continentes",
                "ayuda4_pregunta3_D":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                "correcta":true
            },
            "respuesta5_pregunta3":{
                "respuesta5_pregunta3_E":"Islas",
                "ayuda5_pregunta3_E":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
            }
        }
    }]
};

function padLeft(nr, n, str){
    return Array(n-String(nr).length+1).join(str||'0')+nr;
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var div_main=$("<div></div>").addClass("main");
    var body=$("body");
    var salto=$("<br>");
    if (typeof informacion.preguntas !== "undefined") {
       $.each(informacion.preguntas, function(i, pregunta){
         var div_pregunta=$("<div></div>");
         var formm=$("<form></form>").attr("action","");
         var index = i+1;
        var pregunta_title=$("<p></p>").text(pregunta['pregunta_'+index]);
         var indexResp = 1;
         $.each(pregunta['respuestas_pregunta'+index], function(j, respuesta){
           var constante = index + "" + padLeft(indexResp, 3);
           var input_pregunta_respuesta=$("<input>",{
             type:"radio", 
             name:"pregunta"+index, 
             value:constante, 
             id:"respuesta"+constante
           });
           var label_input_pregunta_respuesta=$("<label></label>").attr("for","respuesta"+constante).text(respuesta['respuesta'+indexResp+"_pregunta"+index+"_"+String.fromCharCode(64+indexResp)]);
           var p_ayuda_pregunta=$("<p></p>").attr("id","ayuda"+constante).text(respuesta['ayuda'+indexResp+"_pregunta"+index+"_"+String.fromCharCode(64+indexResp)]);
             formm.append(input_pregunta_respuesta).append(label_input_pregunta_respuesta).append(p_ayuda_pregunta).append(salto);
           indexResp++;
         });
         div_main.prepend(
            div_pregunta.prepend(pregunta_title).append(formm)
         );
       });
       body.append(div_main);
    }
    
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

> Sin embargo:

Lo mas conveniente sería reestructurar el JSON. Colocarlo de ésta manera sería mas genérico todo el código.

```js
var informacion={
    "titulo":"Pratica 1",
    "cantidad_Preguntas":3,
    "preguntas":[{
        "titulo":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
        "respuestas":[
            {
                "texto":"Países",
                "ayuda":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
            },{
                "texto":"Municipios",
                "ayuda":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },{
                "texto":"Estados_/_provincias",
                "ayuda":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },{
                "texto":"Continentes",
                "ayuda":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                "correcta":true
            },{
                "texto":"Islas",
                "ayuda":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
            }
        ]
    },{
        "titulo":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
        "respuestas":[
            {
                "texto":"Países",
                "ayuda":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
            },{
                "texto":"Municipios",
                "ayuda":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },{
                "texto":"Estados_/_provincias",
                "ayuda":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },{
                "texto":"Continentes",
                "ayuda":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                "correcta":true
            },{
                "texto":"Islas",
                "ayuda":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
            }
        ]
    },{
        "titulo":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
        "respuestas":[
            {
                "texto":"Países",
                "ayuda":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
            },{
                "texto":"Municipios",
                "ayuda":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },{
                "texto":"Estados_/_provincias",
                "ayuda":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
            },{
                "texto":"Continentes",
                "ayuda":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                "correcta":true
            },{
                "texto":"Islas",
                "ayuda":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
            }
        ]
    }]
};

function padLeft(nr, n, str){
    return Array(n-String(nr).length+1).join(str||'0')+nr;
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var div_main=$("<div></div>").addClass("main");
    var body=$("body");
    var salto=$("<br>");
    if (typeof informacion.preguntas !== "undefined") {
       $.each(informacion.preguntas, function(i, pregunta){
         var div_pregunta=$("<div></div>");
         var formm=$("<form></form>").attr("action","");
         var index = i+1;
        var pregunta_title=$("<p></p>").text(pregunta['titulo']);
         var indexResp = 1;
         $.each(pregunta['respuestas'], function(j, respuesta){
           var constante = index + "" + padLeft(indexResp, 3);
           var input_pregunta_respuesta=$("<input>",{
             type:"radio", 
             name:"pregunta"+index, 
             value:constante, 
             id:"respuesta"+constante
           });
           var label_input_pregunta_respuesta=$("<label></label>").attr("for","respuesta"+constante).text(respuesta['texto']);
           var p_ayuda_pregunta=$("<p></p>").attr("id","ayuda"+constante).text(respuesta['ayuda']);
             formm.append(input_pregunta_respuesta).append(label_input_pregunta_respuesta).append(p_ayuda_pregunta).append(salto);
           indexResp++;
         });
         div_main.prepend(
            div_pregunta.prepend(pregunta_title).append(formm)
         );
       });
       body.append(div_main);
    }
    
});
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

Comment: me puedes explicar tu funcion padLeft, porfavor

Comment: @JorgeGutierrezYañez basándose en la función "padStart"(https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart) la funcion padLeft rellena hacia la izquierda la cadena 'nr' con el valor dado en 'str'. Aunque por defecto está el 0. Estos es para transformar "3" a "003". En caso de que sea superior a 10 no colocar "00"+"10" sino mostrar "010".